# Passing data from template to typescript file within component in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there a way i can pass some data from template to .ts file of same component.Scenario is suppose I have a loop running in template and lets say at i==3 i want to make an API call and then at 6 suppose same api call but with some other filtered data. So eventually i have to pass index so that when it reaches to specific value i can filter data accordingly.it is only within a single component so data binding is not an option and also i thought about 2 way binding but i am no input field here in this scenario.Please suggest.

Comment: Please use the angular tag for angular 2+ questions. Angularjs is used for angular 1 questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on click like the example that I have attached, and then you can make an API call inside the method on click and pass the data accordingly

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/lx9eBU?p=preview`
```